# How to parse a Twitter object from Abraham's twitter class in php?

Tags: php, parsing, twitter

I'm using Abrahams twitter class to search twitter, but can't parse the data. I'm totally stuck, getting different errors whatever i do.

Here's a snippet of the object (?) I am trying to parse:

```
stdClass Object (
    [statuses] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [metadata] => stdClass Object (
                [result_type] => recent
                [iso_language_code] => nl
            )
            [created_at] => Mon Jun 17 16:17:52 +0000 2013
            [id] => 346662990684233731
            [id_str] => 346662990684233731
            [text] => RT @433NL: Als Tahiti vanavond scoort tegen Nigeria volgen we iedereen terug die deze tweet retweet! #confed #433NL
            [source] => Twitter for iPhone
            [truncated] =>
            [in_reply_to_status_id] =>
            [in_reply_to_status_id_str] =
```

What do I need to do in order to parse every piece of data for every tweet? Is there something I have to do with the source data before I can parse it?

Many thanks if you are able to help.

If I can remove the StdClassObject references, I imagine I could parse this easily. How could that be achieved?

Edit: the code is not json, but the original source is a json file.

Comment: what you posted in not json

Comment: removed json references.

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the complete object, but you probably need to loop through `$object->statuses` or something similar and get the information you need in the loop.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What data are you trying to parse? What errors are you getting?

Comment: @jeroen exactly, but i don't know how. Is there a way to change it into a simple associative array that i can parse with my basic php skills?

Comment: FOUND a function that turns the object into an array, which enabled me to parse it.

Comment: You might as well read up on objects, for basic usage (like here...) they're not that different from arrays but they offer a lot more functionalities if you want to dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Abraham's Twitter class get function's source code](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/master/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php#L144), it returns a json_decoded array of PHP objects, as the one you showed us. You could simply do:

```
$statuses = $connection->get('whatever arguments your using');
if (!empty($statuses)) {
    foreach ($statuses as $status) {
        echo "{$status->text}\n",
             "sent from {$status->source} at {$status->created_at}\n\n";
    }
}
```

For your object the output would be something like:

```
RT @433NL: Als Tahiti vanavond scoort tegen Nigeria volgen we iedereen terug die deze tweet retweet! #confed #433NL
sent from Twitter for iPhone at Mon Jun 17 16:17:52 +0000 2013
```

There are some alternative solutions, but this is already simple enough, so I wouldn't bother reinventing the wheel.